# How to listen for Bootstrap 5 Modal hidden event using Vue.js 3

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, bootstrap5-modal

I recently started a project using Vue.js and am finding myself having a hard time adjusting to the "Vue" way of doing things (my past few projects have used jQuery).

Anyways, I have a Bootstrap modal which contains a form. I want to be able to clear this form when the user exits the modal. Using jQuery I can simply do: `$('#modalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {  // do something }`

I can't seem to figure out how to listen for this modal close/hidden event using Vue 3 and Bootstrap 5 (Note: I am not using BootstrapVue).

Edit - A commenter asked me to create a sandbox. [Here is the code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-morning-9zv44q?file=/src/components/ModalParent.vue)

Note: I'd like to be able to detect when the Bootstrap modal is hidden and clear the form inputs. This would mainly occur when a user begins to enter data in the form and closes the modal early. I'd also like to swap the modal from "editing" mode back to the initial view when the modal is hidden. I figure I can figure both of these things out easily if I just knew how to listen for the hidden.bs.modal event using Vue. I realize I could probably install jQuery; however, my understanding is that DOM updates are quick/efficient using Vue due to the V-dom. So, I don't think it makes sense to use jQuery. Furthermore, I don't want to add more unnecessary dependencies to the project.

Comment: Do you mind making a quick sandbox before I try helping you? I would appreciate being able to tinker with the vanilla bootstrap js before I make an recommendations. Theoretically, one could use document.getElementById inside an onMounted hook and configure an event listener from there.

Comment: @Issayah I edited my question. The link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-morning-9zv44q?file=/src/components/ModalParent.vue

Comment: I ended up solving my problem by opting to clear the form/swapping modal from "editing" mode back to the initial view when the modal is opened (using onclick) as opposed to when the modal is hidden. While I would not say this is the ideal solution, it works. I will leave the question open though since this solution does not answer the question.